# Proxy server through python doesn't capture all of the requests made

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server

I made a python server bound and listening to a certain port, used port forwarding to connect an android to the said port and monitored the captured requests. However upon crosschecking the captures to that of Fiddler it shows several requests gone unchecked.

The server-

```
import socket
import _thread
import sys

ip = '192.168.1.2'
listening_port = 8888

max_conn = 5
buffer_size = 65536

def start():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((ip , listening_port))
        s.listen(max_conn)

        print('Initializing Socket..Done')
        print('Sockets bound successfully')
        print('Server Started..')

    except:
        print('Unable To Initialize')
        sys.exit()

    while True:
        try:
            conn , addr = s.accept()
            _thread.start_new_thread(conn_string , (conn,addr))

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Proxy Shutting Down')
            sys.exit()

    s.close()

def conn_string(conn,addr):

    data = conn.recv(buffer_size)

    port = addr[1]
    print('Receiving form Port - ' , port)

    print(data)
    print('--'*20)

start()
```

Comment: It is unclear how your proxy is configured at the client and what it actually does after the accept. I guess the problem is in these areas which you don't show.

Comment: To configure the client all I did was use the android port forwarding, the modify network think after long pressing the connected wifi, defined a proxy and set to the local address of the computer on a particular port, namely 8888 as in the code above and in regards to the stuff happening after the connection, it spawns a new thread for each connection and reads the incoming data

Comment: Based on the few details so far my guess is that you don't implement a proper HTTP proxy in the code you've shown, i.e. don't properly read HTTP request and response and thus don't handle the case with several requests inside the same TCP connection well. But this is just a guess based on the assumption that you don't show this part of the code since you don't treat it as relevant for the problem.